# Can't move imported animation in DopeSheet?

Tags: animation, keyframes, pose-mode

Blender 3.2.0 June 2022. I imported this nice man into my two object scene. He comes with a nice animation. I can't move the animation to begin at a different frame.

I've tried selecting all and moving with G, but the third row on the DopeSheet which has many dots and controls the animation does not move with the rest of the keyframes in the other rows.

I've also tried to copy/paste everything, but that third row won't copy/paste either. It is uncopyable and stays put.

Whole view. I see no constraints imported shown on this views right bottom panel:

[image: Blender GUI can't move animation]

Zoom in on the DopeSheet while I'm hitting G with everything selected. See how that third row isn't moving? (I have all the location/rotation keyframes deselected because I want him rotated and positioned where I have him shown.)

[image: DopeSheet keyframes for animation won't move or drag.]

Comment: Could you please share the armature only? https://blend-exchange.com/